# What is the preferred method to change a class on a non-observable value in Knockout 3?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have an observable array `items`. A unordered list is generated forming a nav. I want to apply the class `active` to the clicked item, and remove it from all others. I've tried setting a static `css: { active: true }` but since `active` is not a real property of items, I'm not sure how to implement it.

I called it a non-observable value because I don't want to associate the `active` class with the items array, only to change it on the DOM as necessary.

```
<ul id='nav' data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="css: {selected: false}">
        <a data-bind="text: name, click: click_nav"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the KO...

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Course 1' }
    ]);
    select_course = function select_course(){
        // set class `active` for this
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the currently "active" item in an observable property on the `AppViewModel` what you can set in the `click_nav` function

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Course 1' },
        { name: 'Course 2' },
        { name: 'Course 3' }
    ]);    
    this.active = ko.observable();
    this.click_nav = function(item){
        this.active(item);
    };
}
```

And you can compare the current item (`$data`) to the `active` in your `css` binding:

```
<ul id='nav' data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="css: {selected: $parent.active() == $data}">
        <a data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.click_nav.bind($parent)"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emCbU/).